# React setState with Filelist using forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to use `setState` with forEach when user drag and drop with multiple files.
Suppose I already have something like :

```
class FileCreate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      files: [],
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(files) {
    if (files && files != undefined) {
      Array.from(files).forEach((file, index) => {
        this.setState({ files: [...this.state.files, file] })
      })
    } else {
      console.log('file error')
    }
  }
}
```

It only returns a result with second file from Filelist when `console.log(this.state.files)`
Is there anything wrong with using `setState()` with `forEach()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forEach` is unnecessary (and problematic).

If files is an array then just:

```
    if (files && files != undefined) {
      this.setState({files:[ ...this.state.files, ...files]});
    } else {
      console.log('file error')
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Didn't know using `forEach` is not popper way to combine with asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1):

That could be due to asynchronous behaviour of `setState`. `forEach` is not asynchronous which is causing the issue. You can try the following:

```
handleChange(files) {
    if (files && files != undefined) {
      let newFiles = [];
      Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
        // Use this approach if you want to change file object else forEach is redundant
        newFiles.push(file);
      });
      this.setState({ files: [...this.state.files, ...newFiles] })
    } else {
      console.log('file error')
    }
 }
```